# CocoaPods: Unable to locate the executable `git`

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I've already installed a pod successfully (SDWebImage) and now trying to add a Library called "MFSideMenu". My Podfile looks the following:

```
platform :ios, '6.0'

pod 'SDWebImage', '3.2'
pod 'MFSideMenu'
```

When i do a "pod install", i get the following (error-) output:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing MFSideMenu (0.4.8)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems                 
/custom_require.rb:31: command not found: git config remote.origin.url
[!] Unable to locate the executable `git`
```

Does anybody know whats the problem here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have git installed.  Most software distributed using CocoaPods uses github for hosting and git for distribution.  You need to [install git](http://www.google.com/search?q=install+git+mac).

Comment: @Owow - please see my answer below, I believe that should resolve your issue

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue but had git installed - I followed the workaround outlined here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6923

Windows binaries end in .exe which CocoaPods doesn't seem to take into account, so editing the file `executable.rb` (mine was in `<RubyLocation>\lib\ruby\gems\2.5.0\gems\cocoapods-1.5.3\lib\cocoapods`) and changing the following lines:

`bin = File.expand_path(program, path)`

to

`bin = File.expand_path(program, path)
exe = bin + ".exe"`

and

`if File.file?(bin) && File.executable?(bin)`

to

`if (File.file?(bin) && File.executable?(bin)) || (File.file?(exe) && File.executable?(exe))`

Resolved it.

Comment: i tried your solution, and i stil have the same issue, any other workaround ?