# pod install command shows error

Tags: ruby, xcode, git, ios7, cocoapods

I'm trying to install a pod file with the following contents

```
>platform :ios, '7.0'

>pod 'Brightcove-Player-SDK', '~> 4.1.5'
```

But when i used the  command '**pod install**' in Terminal, i got the following error.

```
[!] Unable to locate the executable `git`
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/claide-0.4.0/lib/claide/command.rb:217:in `run':undefined method `verbose?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:51:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/bin/pod:24
from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
from /usr/bin/pod:23
```

Could someone please explain what the problem is? 
I checked this solution on https://stackoverflow.com/a/18356219/3150731 according to that, installing github should have fixed the problem but, that also did not work in my case.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems where not with the downloading i downloaded everything and installed cocoa pods but was not able to install my pod file in my project workspace as i didn't create an username and email for the git. After doing that i was able to install my pod file

following are the codes to set your username and emailid for your git using terminal

> git config --global user.name "Firstname Lastname"
>   git config --global user.email "your_email@youremail.com"

Answer (score 0):

The ruby script is complaining that `git` cannot be found. To fix that, you have got to install [`git-scm`](http://git-scm.com/). Make sure to integrate it with terminal..

Comment: how do you integrate it with terminal?

Comment: I think it presents you with options.. Although am not sure now, as I haven't updated my git for quite a while

Comment: Sorry it doesn't (present you options).. What does `which git` output? After you install git, try `pod install` again, it will work

Comment: i installed the `git-scm` and tried `pod install` again but it still gives the same error :(

Comment: @jerzo can you launch `git` from the terminal?

Comment: What do you mean?If i execute `git` i get the usual help section of the terminal saying what all command combinations are possible using the git command

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to have installed Git in your computer, download from here:

> http://git-scm.com/download/mac

One you have it, run next command:

> sudo gem install cocoapods

And finally, you can install dependencies in your proyect:

> pod install