# Ionic - Add/Remove phonegap-push-plugin - CocoaPods was not found

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cocoapods

I'm writing an Ionic app but I'm getting so many issues. One issue in particular is that when I try to add the phonegap-push-plugin using the command

```
sudo ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push
```

I get the below error:

```
Error: CocoaPods was not found. Please install version 1.0.1 or greater from https://cocoapods.org/
```

I've obviously tried installing this software as the error suggests, but I cannot find version 1.0.1 anywhere.

I'd also like to understand what this is required for and why Ionic thinks it needs it.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 89, accepted):

To install `push` you must first install `cocoapods`. Follow these steps on your terminal in the Ionic project directory.

First remove what you tried to install

```
ionic cordova plugin remove phonegap-plugin-push
```

Next install cocoapods

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then you need to sync the cocoapods repo

```
pod setup
```

> This may take a while

Finally install `push`

```
ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="XXXXXXX"
```

Comment: This fixes the issue. Thank you.

Comment: if "pod setup" does not work / pod is not known, try this: `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`

Comment: I get an error:!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. Without sudo it will not work..

Comment: `[!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root` after following above steps

Comment: Ionic3 the correct command is `ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="XXXXXXX"`

Comment: I am facing the same problem here, with my user every command I have use "sudo" and everything works but now with this CocoaPods it will not add the plugin to iOS because of this, what can I do? I removed the iOS platform for now because I am testing only in Android but soon I will need to add it again.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Below worked for me on windows 10.

Problem: “You cannot run CocoaPods as root.”
Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37451422/3368558

After following steps mentioned in above link, I got below issue.

Problem: "Unable to locate the executable git"
Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53204534/5492926

Comment: where to get the SENDER_ID ??

Answer (score 4):

The accepted solution to this didn't work for me, I had to install an older version of cocoapods:

`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`
If using brew, run this too: `brew uninstall cocoapods`

`sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.7.5`
`pod setup`

Then reinstall the plugin with `ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="XXXXXXX"`

(As per part of https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41253)

Answer (score 1):

Try without "sudo":
**cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="XXXXXXX"**

Comment: Using sudo is considered to be bad practise unless you have been using sudo that have destroyed the permission system on your computer. Sudo should only be used when there is a direct need for that.