# The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cocoapods

i tried to install pod on ios project but getting this errors 
diff: /Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation .
please suggest me something.

Comment: Open your project's folder. Delete the Podfile.lock file. Run 'pod install" again.

Comment: i tried this did't work for me

Answer (score 2):

This will helpful for you. Try this command in your project folder

```
pod deintegrate --verbose    
pod install --verbose
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , I have already solved this issue earlier

Comment: @sunil kalwani I am facing the same issue, how did you solve it?

Comment: please uninstall pod dependencies from your project and then install new pod with exact cmds that are in documents

Answer (score 0):

Delete your podfile.lock file and try running pod install again.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `pod install` from the project directory. Error *"Podfile.lock: No such file or directory"* means you're running it from inappropriate location.

Comment: i am using ionic platform and podfile.lock is present with xcodeproject file but when i run on device its show above errors

Comment: @sunielkalwani, I don't have experience with ionic. Could you try solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/41157697/1986600 ?

Comment: in the above-referenced link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41079014/ionic-add-remove-phonegap-push-plugin-cocoapods-was-not-found/41157697#41157697 there is reference to running the command "pod setup" which I had not previously done.  I ran that command, closed xcode, removed ios via "ionic cordova platform remove ios" then added it back via "ionic cordova platform add ios" and was able to open xcode and build successfully.

Comment: @RalphHinkley Thank you much, really <3

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and first of all navigate to the root directory of your application, by using "cd" and then drag and drop your project in terminal. Hit enter and the path will be selected. Use "ls" command to verify that there the xcodeproject file is in that folder. Only then run "pod install" command.

Comment: i am using ionic platform and podfile.lock is present with xcodeproject file but when i run on device its show above errors

Answer (score 0):

For me, this error occurs first

> #### Error
>
> ```
> ArgumentError - invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII,
> ```

After the build, the sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock ...

After solved the first error, build successfully.

Solution:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1036

Add export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8" to ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and it turned out to be an issue with the Ruby version number.

I was getting this error:

```
The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
```

After trying many, many solutions, including much of what is included in this thread I wound up hacking the pod file located at: `usr/local/bin/pod`

I corrected the first line to point to the ruby version that actually existed on my machine. I changed:

```
#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
```

to

```
#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
```

After days of struggling, changing a 3 to a 6 fixed everything. You'll need to check what version of Ruby is actually running on your machine then check the pod file to see if this is the problem. Remember to save a copy of the original pod file in case you mess up.